# Javascript - Redirect to and from specific pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Newb to Javascript here.

I'm creating a touchscreen terminal in my store for customers, and I need the terminals to redirect back to their main pages after an idle time, due to customers likely moving through the website and not bringing it back to the main page themselves.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  
  

var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
  $(this).scroll(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});
 function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
     if ((idleTime > 9) && (myPath === '/wp/'))   { // 10 seconds
       window.location.href = "http://localhost/wp";
    } else if ((idleTime > 9) && (myPath === '/wp/juice-intro/')) {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost/wp/juice-intro"; }
 
}

  });
```

The problem is the 'View Products' button on /wp/ goes to /wp/store/, and the 'View Products' button on /wp/juice-intro/ goes to /wp/store/Juice-c26616346 .
And the problem beyond this is that each product that is clicked on past either of those pages is /wp/store/My-Product-a329834

So I need a way of storing some kind of value that remembers which page each terminal originally loaded on.

Comment: localStorage might help https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Interesting question.  I believe what you're asking for can be implemented using the `window.history` api (sorry, no time to try this out today)

Comment: You can use history  of js instead of  window.location.href for example  window.history.go(-1);  will  move you back to previous page

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome you can go back to the first page that the current browser tab opened using

```
window.history.go( 1 - window.history.length );
```

Comment: This solution only works if you assume the browser window can only be opened on the start page of the application.  Probably a fairly safe assumption given the scenario - but it isn't explicitly stated

Comment: `So I need a way of storing some kind of value that remembers which page each terminal originally loaded on.` Seems pretty explicitly stated.

Comment: But I have no idea what the terminal is or what browser it will be using...

Comment: You still don't really know what the history is going to contain.  Your answer is probably going to work most of the time, but it's a brute force method that makes an assumption that could be incorrect for a number of reasons

Comment: @Tibrogargan that this method breaks if you open a tab with a default url and then load your intended "home" page, your application opens new tabs, or if it allows external links which can pollute or modify the history. I have used this code in a museum install on a site with no external links running on tablets in kiosk mode and it has held up  fine in that situation.

Comment: It would work in an environment similar to a kiosk.  This is why I explicitly said "Probably a fairly safe assumption", but it's still an assumption.  Also, you don't answer the OPs requirement (the one that, ironically, you quoted) - despite the fact that the same API you use offers a solution that does exactly that.

Comment: Solution posted by JasonB is actually EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood you need to navigate back from  /wp/store/My-Product-a329834 page to previous page to do this you can try document.referrer

```
if (idleTime > 9 )   { // 10 seconds
       window.location.href = document.referrer;
    }
```